# How to rotate a polar plot without rotating the grid lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, polarplot

[image]

Please, how do I rotate the following polar plot without rotating its grid lines and polar axis lines? To make it clearer, I just want to rotate the petals alone without rotating any axis or grid lines.

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}[rotate=72]
     \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300] {cos(5*x)};
   \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounds like a math problem, not a TeX one: `cos(5*x + 72)`?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it didn’t work. It’s actually a TeX problem. I just want to use the rotate option in the polaraxis environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    
    \begin{document}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{polaraxis}
                \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300,rotate=30] {cos(5*x)};
            \end{polaraxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{document}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Attention**: The plot is invariant for rotations of 72°. So I used 30° to see the rotation.

Comment: Thanks for giving attention to my question. I was working with more than one domain but with this, I have been able to move forward.  I tried your suggestion before posting, for one domain instead of all domains. Your answer prompted me to do the right thing. I really appreciate.